# What does python depend on while executing a script?

Tags: python, dependencies, environment-variables

#### The awkward scenario

I am developing a python package and would like to make use of an external package, that was not written by myself, as a dependency.

Since the external package is quite complex it also comes with all kinds of surplus software like its own bash or python executable. Naturally I do not want to use the bash or the delivered python executable but rather use my own IDE setup.

I therefore started to check the environment variables of the delivered bash like the *PATH*, *PYTHONPATH* or the *LD_LIBRARAY_PATH* (the external package relies on compiled shared objects).

After setting those environment variables I tried to run a simple "Hello World" script from within my IDE but did not succeed (which is why I am posting here^^). On the other hand if I run the same script from within the delivered bash it runs without a problem.

#### Questions

- What kind of dependencies does python, or even more complex, python code rely on?
- Is there a way to check why the script executed from two different environments behaves differently?

The problem I have running the script from within my IDE is a bug in the package and not some *cannot find shared object* or *unable to load module ...* or something. But why does it behave differently?

What other issues than environment variables might there be to make two different python executables run exactly the same?

Comment: This is open-ended. A Python package can depend on any other Python package, on a C, C++ or Fortran library, on external programs...

Comment: @larsmans I agree. But I am trying to reproduce the exact state with the environment variables. And with the same state python should generate the same results!?

Answer (score 1):

All environment variables used by Python are listed here: [Python environment variables](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)

Ensure that your Python interpreter has the same version than the external one .

Comment: I just pickled the `os.environ` dictionary from the delivired bash and used that dictionary in my own IDE and was able to run my "Hello World" script. Is there a way to make the `os.environ` dictionary hold the same values as in the delivered bash?

Comment: I would rather try to find out which of the environment variables is causing trouble...

Comment: Right, that is what I am after. The pickle only showed that it is possible. Do you have an idea how I could efficiently find out what environment variables cause the trouble?